# Retrofit - Calling REST services with POST method

Tags: android, retrofit

I am stuck by my first using of Retrofit2 library for callin REST API service with POST method.

I have tried to learn with tutorial created by Prabeesh (youtube). But even it seems my logic of APIinterface, ApiClient is nearly the same, code is not working.

Problem is that tutorial is shown with GET method, and I'm not pretty sure whether my analogic interpretation for POST method is correct..

Calling service with webbrowser (GET method) is succesfull and user is created. API REST client is showing this successfull response as well (POST method):

```
Content-Length: 56
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 21 Aug 2017 08:18:51 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.25
```

for this request on REST service created on localhost using PHP:

```
http://localhost/forman/forman/register/newUser/newSurname/geywh@test.com/password/CZE/2017-07-11/1/1/2017-07-12%2000:00:00.000000/2017-07-12%2000:00:00.000000
```

Method `createUser` in index.php should be called on back-end service:

```
$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->post('/register/{first_name}/{sur_name}/{email}/{password} /{country}/{birthday}/{fav_driver}/{fav_team}/{created}/{last_login}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
$first_name = $request->getAttribute('first_name');
$sur_name = $request->getAttribute('sur_name');
$email = $request->getAttribute('email');
$password = $request->getAttribute('password');
$country = $request->getAttribute('country');
$birthday = $request->getAttribute('birthday');
$fav_driver = $request->getAttribute('fav_driver');
$fav_team = $request->getAttribute('fav_team');
$created = $request->getAttribute('created');
$last_login = $request->getAttribute('last_login'); 

$db = new dbhandler();
$res = $db->createUser($first_name, $sur_name, $email, $password, $country, $birthday, $fav_driver, $fav_team, $created, $last_login);

        if ($res == USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY) {
            $response->getBody()->write("Yep, user added!!!!, $first_name $sur_name");
        } else if ($res == USER_CREATE_FAILED) {
            $response->getBody()->write("Error!!!, $first_name $sur_name");
        } 

$response->getBody()->write("Hello, $first_name $sur_name");
return $response;
});
$app->run();
?>
```

So, I built the API Interface with POST method calling `/register` site defined in .htaccess:

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@POST("/register")
Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);}
```

I am also using User class with constructor, getters, setters and serialized to fields on REST service..

```
public class User {
//Constructor
public User(String first_name, String sur_name, String email, String password, String country, String birthday, int fav_driver, int fav_team, String created, String last_login) {
}
@SerializedName("first_name")
public String first_name;
@SerializedName("sur_name")
public String sur_name;
@SerializedName("email")
public String email;
@SerializedName("password")
public String password;
@SerializedName("country")
public String country;
@SerializedName("birthday")
public String birthday;
@SerializedName("fav_driver")
public Integer fav_driver;
@SerializedName("fav_team")
public Integer fav_team;
@SerializedName("created")
public String created;
@SerializedName("last_login")
public String last_login;

// Setters
public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}
public void setSur_name(String sur_name) {
    this.sur_name = sur_name;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
    this.birthday = birthday;
}
public void setFav_driver(Integer fav_driver) {
    this.fav_driver = fav_driver;
}
public void setFav_team(Integer fav_team) {
    this.fav_team = fav_team;
}
public void setCreated(String created) {
    this.created = created;
}
public void setLast_login(String last_login) {
    this.last_login = last_login;
}

// Getters
public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}
public String getSur_name() {
    return sur_name;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public String getBirthday() {
    return birthday;
}
public Integer getFav_driver() {
    return fav_driver;
}
public Integer getFav_team() {
    return fav_team;
}
public String getCreated() {
    return created;
}
public String getLast_login() {
    return last_login;
}
}
```

Api Client creating retrofit instance:

```
public class ApiClient {
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost/forman/forman/";
public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getApiClient()  {

    if(retrofit==null) {

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

And call API interface and API client during onClick method in my code:

```
public void addButtonClickListener() {
    final Context context = this;

    Button confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_save_reg);
    confirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {



            TextView firstname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            String first_name = (String) firstname.getText().toString();

            TextView surname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            String sur_name = (String) surname.getText().toString();

            TextView email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reg_et_email);
            String e_mail = (String) email.getText().toString();

            TextView password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
            String pass = (String) email.getText().toString();

            TextView country_reg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reg_tv_country);
            String country = (String) country_reg.getText().toString();

            TextView birthday_reg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.birthday_reg);
            String birthday = (String) birthday_reg.getText().toString();

//                TextView fav_driver = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
//                Integer favdriver = Integer.valueOf((String) fav_driver.getText().toString());
//
//                TextView fav_team = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewFavTeam);
//                Integer favteam = Integer.valueOf((String) fav_team.getText().toString());

            User user = new User(first_name, sur_name, e_mail, pass, country, birthday, 1, 1, "2017-07-12 00:00:00.000000", "2017-07-12 00:00:00.000000");

            final ApiInterface apiInterface;

            apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

            Call<User> call = apiInterface.createUser(user);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

                    Log.d("CREATION", "Check this, because this and    OnFailure never happened!");

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable throwable) {

                }
            });


        }

    });

}
```

Sorry, for plenty of code, bude I am novice in Android, Java, Retrofit.. so, currently I am not pretty sure in any part of code. I would really appreciate your help or I would put the bullet into my head soon :)

Next time, I will learn on simple model with couple of field only..

Thank you for everyone checking my problem,

Have a nice day,
Jiri

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove slash in retrofit annotation. Your base url already has slash in the end. As result you are trying to send data to

```
http://localhost/forman/forman//register
```

The current code

```
@POST("/register")
```

The new code

```
@POST("register")
```

Comment: Improve done, but still not working. The same behavior like befor - that mean's  call.enqueue is not getting respone. Callback - onResponse and onFailure is just skipped, not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

As I am still stuck I minimized my code (by creating API test project) and extract just the most important component of the code, to avoid some misunderstanding and make it easier even for you, because it is not still clear for me..

I am calling `enqueue` method in onCreate activity as asynchronous request to avoid creating background thread manually..

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    User user = new User("John", "Markovicz", "john-markovicz@email.com", "password", "UK", "2017-07-11", 1, 1, "2017-07-12 00:00:00.000000", "2017-07-12 00:00:00.000000" );

    APIInterface apiinterface = APIclient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
    Call<User> call = apiinterface.createUser(user);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            User result = response.body();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable throwable) {
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, I would like to save the the user on back-end DB. Instance of user is created by using constructor defined in User class (I expect that no setters and getters are necessary?):

```
public class User {
public User(String first_name, String sur_name, String email, String password, String country, String birthday, Integer fav_driver, Integer fav_team, String created, String last_login) {
}
}
```

This Interface and this Retrofit instance I'm using for setting the data to back-end:

```
public interface APIInterface {

@POST("register")
Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);
}
```

Retrofit instance:

```
public class APIclient {

public static Retrofit getClient() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost/forman/forman/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

No error is shown. I had also some trouble with settings of Android SDK, but after installing API 26 inside I am not getting any error in logcat.
I tested once agin POST method via Advanced REST client and this payload request is processed correctly and stored in DB:

Location:

```
http: //localhost/forman/forman/register
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Payload:

```
first_name=First_name&sur_name=Sur_name&email=Test@gmail.com&password=password&country=CZE&birthday=2017-07-11&fav_driver=1&fav_team=1&created=2017-07-12 00:00:00.000000&last_login=2017-07-12 00:00:00.000000
```

Does anybody have the experience to validate my simple code for this?

Thank you,
Jiri

Comment: Can you be more specific? You have sent post request. What is server response? What http code? Have you captured your server logs? Also, you should setup headers for your request: Accept and Content-Type

Comment: Weird, it seems that this POST request is not logged on server in access.log at all..  I will continue tommorow to check this and also setup headers..thank you

Comment: I suggest to use Wireshark to capture packets and see what are you actually sending to server